# What is the difference between pgr_createtopology and pgr_createverticestable?

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting

I'm using pgRouting and I'm going through the manual (Release 2.1.0) and in chapter five, it says:

• pgr_createTopology - to create a topology based on the geometry.

• pgr_createVerticesTable - to reconstruct the vertices table based on the source and target information.

When I run them, I get the exact same outputs. Both pgr_createtopology and pgr_createverticestable give me a new layer public.network_vertices_pgr with:

```
              id|cnt|chk|ein|eou|the_geom
```

As far as I can tell the two functions are doing the exact same thing, and it would be redundant to run both of them, I just wanted to see if there is a difference that I'm overlooking.

Comment: `pgr_createTopology` populates the `source` & `target` columns of the given network table by finding its *geometric* connectivity (intersection of endpoints, with optional threshold), and produces the nodes table as a 'side effect'. `pgr_createVerticeTable` recreates the node table by *reading out previously populated* `source` & `target` columns of the edge table.

Comment: The comment before is correct, just adding, that `pgr_createVerticeTable` can be handy, if you copied a network table into a new daatabase and forgot to also copy the vertices table. Or sometimes your data already has `source` and `target` column and you want to have a list of all nodes.